# UK Uni: modify FTE after offer?

Tags: job, united-kingdom, visa, recruiting

This might be a silly question, apologies in advance.

I've received an informal offer for a fixed-term, part-time (0.3FTE) teaching position at a UK university. Now, because of Brexit, as a EU national I need a visa to work in the UK -- however, the [Skilled Worker visa](https://www.gov.uk/skilled-worker-visa) requires a certain minimum salary, which this position doesn't reach.

Obviously this is something both myself and the employer should have caught earlier, but we didn't.

Moving up within the pay grade isn't nearly enough. One way to fix it would be to adjust the post to something like 0.6FTE. Is this something I can reasonably suggest? Or would it involve redoing the whole recruitment process.

(I considered other visa options, but none seem to apply to such a fixed-term, entry-level, teaching-only position)

EDIT: comments below are correct: NO, it doesn't hurt to ask. And YES, it's out of budget.
Lesson learned: when applying for a part-time position, make sure you read the visa fine print.

Comment: Not a silly question, but off topic as it relates the laws of UK and employment generally, not specific to academia.  See: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: I don't think it would require redoing the recruitment process, but I can't imagine a university advertising a 0.3FTE position if they had the money for a 0.6FTE position...

Comment: _Is this something I can reasonably suggest?_ What other alternative do you have? It sounds like you cannot legally reside in the UK with the position you were offered. Whether the request to change it is reasonable or not seems beside the point.

Comment: Is the university even aware of the problem? If not, you should certainly tell them.  In that connection, you can suggest your solution but also ask whether they see another solution.

Comment: @AndreasBlass yes, they're aware. We have been discussing (and running out of) possible options since they made the offer.

Comment: @Buffy not completely. It's about what a department is able to do, which might be less flexible than other employers in this situation.

Comment: What's your ONS occupation code? The minimum salary depends on this, so presumably you (or someone in the department) already knows. If not, you can look it up at https://onsdigital.github.io/dp-classification-tools/standard-occupational-classification/ONS_SOC_occupation_coding_tool.html

Comment: A part time fixed term job is normally a bad deal for the employee.

Answer (score 1):

Not a silly question, and not something to feel awful about missing given that the Brexit rollout hasn't exactly been...smooth.

**Definitely ask your department if they have an extra 0.3FTE worth of work you can do. Staffing needs can change unexpectedly, so even if they didn't need 0.6FTE when you applied they might now.** For example, if you can't accept the job because of visa issues, they'll suddenly have a new opening!

If they can't hire you to do more of the same job, you might consider looking into whether other parts of the university (say, another department in a related field) would hire you. If the university is your sponsor it may not matter if you're doing work in multiple departments. (note: *I'm not a lawyer, I have no idea if the university is the sponsor or if you're required to work in only one department*).

Also, you presumably already know this, but just in case it hasn't come up, you may qualify for a lower salary threshold if you meet one of [the following criteria](https://www.gov.uk/skilled-worker-visa):

> - your job is in a shortage occupation
> - you’re under 26, studying or a recent graduate, or in professional training
> - you have a science, technology, engineering or maths (STEM) PhD level qualification that’s relevant to your job (if you have a relevant PhD level qualification in any other subject your salary must be at least £23,040)
> - you have a postdoctoral position in science or higher education